# Difference between "quiche" and "tarte"

Tags: usage, registre-familier

I just said in conversation:

> Quoi, vous ne croyiez tout de même pas que j’allais m’occuper de la tambouille moi-même ? Je suis une **quiche** en cuisine !

A *quiche* person is *nul* at some activity, hands down, but I'm a bit fuzzy on how a *tarte* person compares, as in "*passer pour une **tarte***" vs "*passer pour une **quiche***".

While their meanings seem to overlap to a certain extent, I don't suppose you can say, for instance, "*je suis une **tarte** en* X" or "*je suis 
**tarte** en* X", can you?

Answer (score 3):

The meanings are close but you can't indeed say *Je suis une tarte en cuisine*.

*Tarte* is mostly used adjectivally:

> *Ta copine, elle est tarte.*

Meaning, she is not brilliant, not clever, boring.

A *quiche* has a more restricted meaning: lacking all the skills required to properly do something.

Comment: À croire que les Français ne raffolent pas des quiches ni des tartes...

Comment: Ils peuvent aussi se foutre des tartes, voire se taper la quiche...

Comment: Can a thing, not a person, be "tarte" just as well? And do you use "tarte" in this specific sense yourself?

Comment: *Tarte* mostly qualify people, but can also be used with things, often still related to people: [«J'aime mon histoire parce qu'elle est tarte», écrit Amélie Nothomb.](https://www.lexpress.fr/informations/affreux-sales-et-mechants_624078.html) and [Qu’est-ce qu’il est tarte, ton look](https://empiredesfous.wordpress.com/category/francais/francais-argot/)  Trouver ces exemples, c'est pas d'la tarte ;-)